# Is it bad practice to change a class' attributes in it's own methods?

Tags: python

Hey just some beginner looking for advice.

```py
class Board():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    
    def SelectSquare(self,direction):
        #based on some value from direction
        self.x += 1
        #or
        self.y += 1

        #return square at self.x and self.y
```

Given the above code, is it bad practice to create attributes that will change inside an object like this?

Comment: No, that's exactly what they're for. One of the main reasons for using classes is for maintaining internal state.

Comment: It's not bad practice for a method to mutate the instance, but it's conventional for a method to either mutate the instance *or* return something.

Comment: This is borderline based on opinion, indeed, there are entire schools of thought that say you should *never mutate anything*. But certainly, it is conventional in OOP for methods to mutate objects.

Comment: No, it's the right thing to do — it's called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) and is a fundamental part of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly fine. It fits with the Object Oriented Programming paradigm, which says ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)):

> A feature of objects is that an object's own procedures can access and often modify the data fields of itself

Just two remarks:

- Use snake_case for your method names, not PascalCase
- If a method mutates properties, then it might be better not to have it return something. When a coder calls this method being aware about the returned value, they may be surprised that there is *also* another, side effect.

  Decide whether the function should *return* something -- in which case it is often better not mutate the instance -- or else does *not* return something, in which case it is perfectly fine to mutate the instance. There are of course exceptions to this rule. The important thing here is that the caller should not be surprised by the "side effects".

Comment: "Use camelCase for your method names, not PascalCase" use *neither* in Python... `snake_case` :)

Comment: There are multiple habits here, but most agree that PascalCase should be reserved for class names.

Comment: True, but *it is explicitly* part of PEP8 to use snake-case.

Comment: OK, I will adapt.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, I was just about to mention that: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
Still, great answer @trincot!

Comment: Quick question, suppose if you were creating a game, and you had the class `Character`, and a method called `move_one_step_foward()`, increasing `x` and `y` by `1` and then returning it would be okay, Correct? The caller knows that they created a character that can move forward from there starting position, so it isn't a surprise. You may also want to draw the new position, which would be handled by another class, so you would definitely need to move and return `x`,`y`.

Comment: Sure, that would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bad practice. If your logic dictates changing an object's attributes, it makes perfect sense to have a method to handle that, as opposed to doing it in an unrelated piece of code, and thus breaking the principle of encapsulation.